# autoinstall/user-data's users section does not work at all?

Tags: 20.04, cloud-init

I try to follow the instruction:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61868231/1492613
- https://gist.github.com/leogallego/a614c61457ed22cb1d960b32de4a1b01#file-ubuntu-cloud-virtualbox-sh-L46-L56

```yaml
autoinstall:
...
  user-data:
    write_files:
      - content: |
          cloud_init_has_run
        path: /cloud_init_flag
    users:
      - default
      - name: kim
        passwd: <hash>
        shell: /bin/bash
        lock-passwd: false
        ssh_pwauth: True
        chpasswd: { expire: False }
        sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
        groups: users, admin
```

Or put the users, as the same level of autoinstall

```yaml
users:
  - default
  - name: kim
    passwd: <hash>
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock-passwd: false
    ssh_pwauth: True
    chpasswd: { expire: False }
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: users, admin
autoinstall:
```

Both users do not work, but the write_files actually works. `ls /home/` does not show kim, but only my default user in identity.

Can anyone explain how to make the users block work?

### update

the passwd seems never work, I tried following commands to create the hash:

- `mkpasswd -m sha512crypt -s`
- `mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 --rounds=4096 -s`

I just put the output hash to `passwd: "<hash>"` but the login always fail with wrong passwd, I can only login with my ssh key. Any idea how to specify the passwd here?

In the /var/log/cloud-init.log we can see:

```
2021-09-30 15:18:39,580 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Adding user testuser
2021-09-30 15:18:39,580 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running hidden command to protect sensitive input/output logstring: ['useradd', 'testuser', '--comment', 'testuser', '--groups', 'users,sudo,admin,cdrom,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,lxd,libvirt', '--password', 'REDACTED', '--shell', '/bin/bash', '-m']
2021-09-30 15:18:39,606 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['passwd', '-l', 'testuser'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
2021-09-30 15:18:39,619 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /etc/sudoers (quiet=False)
```

I finally found out why it does not work, the /etc/shadow is somehow wrong:

```
testuser:!$6$02H0ZRN.QfL7$G8/Jh7bZNlIEPAsGKZOBUog89a559t/LSWXAyqncOpJytlls8hsGHQgeBdWGoYhedZ0v7bsVNFlRf/S0Tusug1:18900:0:99999:7:::
```

The extra `!` cause the failure. Remove it make it works. Is this a bug or there is some

correct flag is: `lock_passwd: false` instead of `lock-passwd: false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me using the `20.04.3` server installer (`subiquity  21.08.2`)

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  # r00tme
  user-data:
    users:
      - default
      - name: kim
        passwd: $6$.c38i4RIqZeF4RtR$hRu2RFep/.6DziHLnRqGOEImb15JT2i.K/F9ojBkK/79zqY30Ll2/xx6QClQfdelLe.ZjpeVYfE8xBBcyLspa/
        lock_passwd: false
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: [adm,sudo]
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
```

A few key points

- this will create the default user, `ubuntu`, that has no password.  It will also create a second user, `kim`, with the given password hash.
- the users do not get created until the first boot.  The installer adds configuration for `cloud-init` to create the users.
- the `groups` had to be in YAML list syntax.
- I did **not** include an `identity` section.

Comment: thanks a lot. The groups works now. But I still cannot make the password work, please see the update

Comment: ah I get it, it need `lock_passwd: false`, it is weird that default is true ...