# provision additional user accounts during autoinstall?

Tags: system-installation, useradd

Is it possible to provision multiple user accounts (eg. security scanning accounts) during autoinstall?  The primary account gets created with user-data:

identity:
hostname: useful
password: *hash here*0
realname: Super Guy
username: ubuntu

Is there a way to create additional accounts?

Should this be handled in a post-install script? If so what is the best way
to create the account without having password clear-text present?  The useradd program doesn't seem to have an option for providing the password hash.

Comment: I may help to know what version of Ubuntu you are using. A must for any question.

Comment: To create multiple users you have to use the `user-data` `users` section and **must remove** the `identity` section.  See these examples https://askubuntu.com/a/1385096/376778 https://askubuntu.com/a/1366399/376778 .  You could also use a post-install script or `late-commands`, but this is the provided method.